# doubt regarding power of graph

Tags: graphs

could you help me in clarifying a doubt regarding how to find square of a graph g from graph g.the doubt occurs on 15th page of the document which I have shown you by the link given.the doubt is that I could see all edges and vertices were correct for square of the graph.But I couldn't see an vertex for sugar,sugar and flour,flour.But it's there for frosting,frosting and eggs,eggs. The link is:http://1drv.ms/1qp7ZDE

Comment: Please make your post self-contained; links break. What is the definition of "square" you are working with, and what is the graph? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 4):

The slides you link do not give a clear definition of what $G^2$ is. On page 8, they say

> - Creating a node pair graph $G^2$ from $G$
> - $\langle(p,q),(a,b)\rangle$ is in $G^2$ if $\langle p,a\rangle$ and $\langle q,b\rangle$ are in $G$

and they give an example. From the examples, it appears that they use $(x,y)$ for the *unordered pair* $\{x,y\}$, but this is never stated. They don't say what the vertex set of $G^2$ is and they don't say that $\langle(p,q),(a,b)\rangle\in E(G)$ if *and only if* $\langle p,a\rangle\in E(G)$ and $\langle q,b\rangle\in E(G)$.
The most natural interpretation would be that the vertex set of $G^2$ is *every* unordered pair $(x,y)$ such that $x,y\in V(G)$, including all pairs $(x,x)$.  That would give the usual [tensor product of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs), except using unordered pairs as the vertex set.

However, the example on page 8 has five vertices in $G$ and only eight in $G^2$ (there should be 15). And, as you say, the bipartite example on pages 14–16 has four vertices on the right side of $G$ but only eight on the right side of $G^2$ (there should be ten).  So, the slides are completely unclear on this point but my best guess is that, yes, there should be vertices [$\langle\mathrm{sugar},\mathrm{sugar}\rangle$](http://www.kongregate.com/games/bontegames/sugar-sugar) and $\langle\mathrm{flour},\mathrm{flour}\rangle$.